# On common eigenbases of commuting operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics

If $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint operators, each of which possesses
a complete set of eigenvectors, then $AB = BA$ if and only if there exists a complete set of eigenvectors which are eigenvectors of both $A$ and $B$.

I know how the proof goes for discrete spectrum with degeneracy accounted, but how can I prove this considering degeneracy of a continuous spectrum?

For example, in the continuous case, to prove that if A and B have a commom complete set of eigenvectors $\implies$ that AB=BA, it is common, when we have no degeneracy, to write down A and B in the following way

$\int da |a⟩⟨a|$ and $\int db |b⟩⟨b|$.

How could I write that considering degeneracy?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: The problem of CSCOs with continuous spectrum is completely solved by Gelfand and Vilenkin in the 4th volume of "Generalized functions" using RHS techniques.

Comment: @Qmechanic yeah, I will post there too.

Comment: @DanielC Do you know if I can get a free pdf of that? This book isn't in my library.